# Cordova passing parameters wrong to native

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've some issue with executing Cordova custom plugin and passing arguments to it.
I'm using function cordova.exec(callback, errCallback, pluginName, pluginAction, pluginArgs), like this:

```
module BlankCordovaApp2 {
"use strict";

export module Application {
    export function initialize() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener('pause', onPause, false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume, false);
        var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
        log({ id: r, value: "test" + r },
            function () { alert('pass') },
            function () { alert('fail') });
    }

    function log (log, callback, errCallback) {
        cordova.exec(callback,
            errCallback,
            "LogstashLogger",
            "LOGGER_SERVICE_ACTION_LOG",
            log
            );
    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    }

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    }

}

window.onload = function () {
    Application.initialize();
}
}
```

This way, cordova is calling my plugin's:
public boolean execute(String action, String rawArgs, CallbackContext callbackContext)
which is fine.

However, I'd like also to pass string and jsonarray to my plugin. Unfortunatelly, whatever I pass to cordova.exec, always execute for (..., String rawArgs, ...) gets called, so:

- cordova.exec(..., "test") calls execute with **"test"** as a rawArgs but WITH double quotes! What on earth...
- cordova.exec(..., [{ id: 1, value: "test1" }, { id: 1, value: "test1" }] calls execute with **[{"id":891,"value":"test891"},{"id":891,"value":"test891"}]** as a String...

It look like calling my function log(...) is doing some strange type casting. But I can call to cordova.exec directly only with string[] as a type, but then when I call cordova.exec(..., [ "test" ]) it should call execute with jsonarray as parameter with one string element, but it's acctualy calling execute with string parameter with value **["test"]**

So question is, how to call cordova.exec properly?

Answer (score 3):

Try something along these lines:

**Javascript**

```
var json1 = {foo: "bar"};
var json2 = {bar: "foo"};

cordova.exec(
    successCallback,
    errorCallback,
    'MyPlugin',
    'myAction',
    [json1,json2]
);
```

**Java**

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if ("myAction".equals(action)){
            JSONObject json1 = args.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject json2 = args.getJSONObject(1);
            callbackContext.success();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a working example project which illustrates how JSON can be passed from Javascript to Java on the Android platform: http://ge.tt/api/1/files/2CJwqVL2/0/blob?download

Comment: Hello Dave, thanks for this, but this is my exact problem. Calling your method, calls execute with String as parameter, not JSONArray. And this string is passed with value: ["{\"foo\":\"bar\"}","{\"bar\":\"foo\"}"].
I'm using cordova tools for visual studio 2015 community.

Comment: Hi again, sorry my mistake, you don't need to stringify the input JSON any more as Cordova now does this for you. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with my VS :) I cannot use your plugin in my project, as the namespace cordova.plugins is not visible - even after building the project...

I also cannot build project if I try to run code from yours src/www/plugin.js by copying code into my index.js, because [json1, json2] cannot be converted to string[]. It looks like my version of cordova is missing some cordova.exec contructors... 

http://www.fotosik.pl/pokaz_obrazek/93bde1c74e358694.html

Comment: Still no idea what is wrong. I've removed everything from VS, installed again VS2013 with Tools for Apache Cordova 3.1 and still there is always called execute with String as parameters, no matter what I put as a args in  cordova.exec from js.